# SSRS: Get Dates from Report Into Header Text Boxes

Tags: reporting-services

My Dataset has Variables @StartDate and @EndDate that I use to describe a Date Range of the Previous Month.

I Cast () both Date variables as Varchar - E.g. Cast(@StartDate As Varchar(10)) As StartDate and then include StartDate and EndDate in my Final Output.

The Report Body/Detail has StartDate and EndDate fields included but Not Visible.

In the Header of the Report, I have a Text Box in which I have the Expression:

```
=ReportItems!StartDate.Value
```

When I run the report, I get the following Warning - and nothing shows in the Test Box in the Header.

```
Warning     [rsInvalidExpressionDataType] The Value expression used in textrun 'StartDate.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' returned a data type that is not valid.
```

When I make the two Date fields in the Report Visible, I see that the Values in there are all "#Error". This part is puzzling ... as the two fields SSMS show the dates in '2021-04-20' format.

One thing I should mention. The working report was created using an earlier version of Visual Studio. I am currently using VS 2017 to create this new report.

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Sincerely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in another thread that I hadn't found before. Sorry. The suggestion was to delete the rdl.Data file for the Report. Worked like a charm. Again, apologies that I didn't find that suggestion before I posted my question.